# Setting iTerm2 as the default terminal (OSX Lion)

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app, iterm2

I would like to set iTerm2 instead of terminal.app as my default terminal.

Go2Shell for example let you open a terminal to the current directory in Finder.
I want to ba able to use iterm2 instad of terminal.app.

I didn't find any answer on the official documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Update: ShellTo is a great alternative to Go2Shell and supports iTerm2

Comment: Default terminal for what? You just launch the one you want and leave the other alone...? Please explain in more detail what you're asking.

Comment: Go2Shell blurb from the app store: *Added support of iTerm, iTerm 2 and even xterm :)*. Just take a look at its preferences. Also, at least for Terminal.app, this feature has been part of the OS for half a year, see [here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#automator) (last item).

Comment: Oh I didn't saw it. My fault!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`Terminal.app` declares itself a handler of the `ssh`, `telnet` and `x-man-page` URL schemes.

It also registers the file extensions `.term` (sessions), `.terminal` (settings), `.tool` and `.command` (scripts), and itself as an editor/viewer for these.

Other than that, there is no *default terminal* in OS X. It's just an application that can handle URL schemes and file types.

---

iTerm is capable of handling all of these except the Terminal.app specific `.term`/`.terminal`.

For the file types, just open the *Get Info* dialog and associate all files of this kind with iTerm. For the URL schemes, you can download and install the preference pane [Default Apps](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) and change the association there. You can also use it as an alternative method of changing the file type associations.

[image]

---

All of these settings are user specific and stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`. You can of course edit it in a suitable editor yourself. It's pretty straightforward. Screenshot of Xcode 4 showing the result of changing `x-man-page` in *Default Apps* preference pane:

> [image]

---

Terminal.app also provides the following *Services* for other applications:

- New Terminal at Folder
- New Terminal Tab at Folder
- Open man page in Terminal
- Search man pages in Terminal

The association with Terminal.app is hard-coded. You need to create your own Services e.g. using Automator and/or AppleScript to replace these.

---

If Terminal is used via its AppleScript API, there is no way to just replace it with iTerm in all cases, as their APIs are quite different. This will often require substantial changes to the programs or scripts doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer. Clear, very informative. New to OSX, I didn't know Default Apps.

Comment: Awesome tool.  Glad it still works well under El Capitan.

Comment: Oh goodness, this is so helpful. I accidentally deleted Terminal.app (or screwed it up so bad it won't open) and this works to fix that, and my React Native builds are using iterm so far so good, knock on wood. THX:D

Comment: [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) is a more recent alternative to RCDefaultApp.

Comment: if you are a React Native developer coming here to find out how to get the React Native launcher to run the metro server in iTerm instead of Terminal, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817359/34315)

Comment: @gabe Alternatively, this answer provides the solution too: "[Terminal.app] registers the file extensions … `.command` (scripts), and itself as an editor/viewer for these. … For the file types, just open the _Get Info_ dialog and associate all files of this kind with iTerm."

Answer (score 90):

You should be able to make `iTerm.app` your default terminal by selecting "Make Default" from the menu bar.

[image: File menu drop down]

Alternatively you can use a keyboard shortcut.

<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for most of my tests. GitHub.app still opens Terminal and so does SublimeText.

Comment: @bfred.it: Sadly, the name of the menu item is misleading: the _only_ thing it does is to run shell scripts opened from _Finder_ in iTerm2 rather than Terminal.
It will _not_ magically cause third-party applications such as GoShell, GitHub, Alfred, ... to use iTerm2, as explained in [Daniel Beck's answer](http://superuser.com/a/379354/139307).

Answer (score 11):

As found on the [ma.ttias.be](https://ma.ttias.be/set-iterm2-default-ssh-handler-mac-osx/) blog, iTerm2 can register itself as the default terminal for some common URL schemes: You just have to check the corresponding schemes at the very bottom of the General tab in the current Profile from iTerm preferences

[image: iTerm > Préférences > Profiles > Général > URL Schemes]

Comment: Most to the point answer IMO.

Answer (score 10):

To provide a **pragmatic summary of the existing answers**:

- **macOS (OS X) does NOT support the concept of a *default terminal***.

  - See [Daniel Beck's helpful answer](https://superuser.com/a/379354/139307) for background information.
  - **`iTerm2`** itself **somewhat misleadingly offers a menu item named `iTerm2 > Make iTerm2 Default Term`** (as presented in [halfcube's answer](https://superuser.com/a/870487/139307)), but the only thing that does is to make ***Finder*** run shell scripts opened from it in iTerm2 (more specifically, it assigns the `shell` role of UTI `public.unix-executable` to Finder) - which is *not* a typical use case.
- Therefore, **applications must be configured INDIVIDUALLY** to use iTerm2 instead of Terminal, **IF they support that**:

  - While the **[`Go2Shell` app](http://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell)** that prompted the OP's question does have a configuration dialog that supports iTerm2 (`open -a Go2Shell -- config`, the application **doesn't seem to work at all as of OSX 10.11.6** (on clicking the toolbar button as of v2.23, the only thing that ever happens is that the configuration dialog comes up, even after having clicked `Install Go2Shell to Finder`).
  - The *paid* alternative mentioned by the OP - application `ShellTo` - also supports iTerm2 *in principle*, but as of this writing doesn't support the *current* version, v3+.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments above Go2Shell can be told to use iTerm2

> To open configuration window follow this steps:
>
> 1. Fire up your favorite terminal program.
> 2. Enter: **open -a Go2Shell --args config**
> 3. Press [return].

[image]

http://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell

Answer (score 1):

What @gef posted was partially what I did.
However, this is what worked for me.

Open your terminal app:

`open -a Go2Shell --args config`

Then on the options copy the following code, you might have to right click and paste as the commands are restricted:

`cd %PATH%;clear;pwd;open -a iTerm.app .;killall Terminal;`

And voila, the terminal app should open give a new parameter to iTerm, then close itself again.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any command once the terminal application is run so in order to run iterm2 instead of terminal application, you can create a script that runs each time the terminal is opened and this script should open iterm and kill terminal app

Steps to create script

- Vi /Applications/run_iterm.sh
- Copy the following commands and paste them in the scrip

  ```
  #! /bin/bash
  open -a iTerm.app
  killall Terminal
  ```
- Save the file
- Chmod 755 /Applications/run_iterm.sh

Now our script is ready, the last step is to run it each time the terminal application is opened
Run terminal
Go to preferences -> General -> shell open with -> select command "complete path" and paste /Applications/./run_iterm.sh inside the textbook
finally close the terminal application and run it again
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5IkV.jpg)

Comment: Wow; configuring a program to automatically kill itself whenever it is started.  What could possibly go wrong?   :-(   ⁠

Answer (score 0):

This thread was for OS X Lion, and seems out-of-date for El Capitan.  However, since I found this page while searching for a way to have XCode launch iTerm instead of Terminal, I thought I'd post my solution.

It's not free, unfortunately, but it can be done using the [Magic Launch](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/magiclaunch/) system preference app.  Using that tool, I set iTerm as the default app for `.term`, `.terminal`, and `.command` extensions.  That did the trick for my needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you expand upon how this software works? Please see [How to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: Are you saying my answer doesn't work anymore for El Capitan? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

To associate whatever type of protocol, ssh,telnet, or even ftp and others to iTerm2 you go to iTerm2 application, choose:
Menu ITerm2 / Preferences / Url Schemes ; Select ssh
[Url Schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVEox.png)

Note that now if you go to your browser (say Chrome or Firefox) you can now open an ssh:// link type using iTerm2 instead of the default terminal app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).