# How to set sourcetree's default terminal to iTerm?

Tags: macos, terminal, sourcetree

When use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to start the Terminal on the right top side, the system will launch a default terminal. How to set it start iTerm app on macOS?

Comment: This is not possible. SourceTree doesn't allow other terminals to be used as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258111/how-to-change-default-terminal-in-source-tree-on-windows) is the same issue on the Windows client.

It is not possible. However, you could add a custom action to open iTerm:

> You can add a custom action in the menu. From the global options go to Custom Actions tab and add an action to Open in Terminal using the console you want. This isn't quite as cool as just hitting the terminal icon, but you can easily accomplish the same outcome.

With iTerm2, [there are some things you could try](https://superuser.com/questions/379342/setting-iterm2-as-the-default-terminal-osx-lion) to override the default terminal system wide. If that works it might be better than using a custom action.